# What is the best practise show the privacy policy urls in react-native app

Tags: react-native

I need to know how the privacy policies are placed in UI for mobile(ios and android) apps.

I have two suggestion

1. Need to add the privacy policy in the registration
2. Settings of the screen

Any other options or better than this approach?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Apple Guideline, User must read your Privacy-policy. So I will suggest you should put it on the registration page.

for more info visit https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/apple-custom-eula-minimum-requirements/